# Is there a cleaner way of building a list of the previous, next months than this?

Tags: python

At first I tried using a timedelta but it doesn't accept months as an argument, so my next working example is this:

```
from datetime import datetime
current_date = datetime.now()

months = []
for month_adjust in range(2, -3, -1): # Order by new to old.
    # If our months are out of bounds we need to change year.
    if current_date.month + month_adjust <= 0:
        year = current_date.year - 1
    elif current_date.month + month_adjust > 12:
        year = current_date.year + 1
    else:
        year = current_date.year
    # Keep the months in bounds.
    month = (current_date.month + month_adjust) % 12
    if month == 0: month = 12
    months.append(current_date.replace(year, month=month, day=1))
```

Is there a cleaner way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546321/how-do-i-calculate-the-date-six-months-from-the-current-date-using-the-datetime), I would do something like :

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
today = date.today()
months = [today + relativedelta(months = +i) for i in range(2,-3,-1)]
```

It's always better not to have to play with the dates manually as so many things can go wrong.

(I don't have access to a machine with relativedelta here so it's not tested but I'm pretty confident it should work)

Comment: That is wonderful, thanks! BTW you can drop the `+` in `+i`. :)

Comment: Also you don't need the `.month` in the list compression as I need the date object.